# Django - loop over list in template to check if a value exists, display something later

Tags: django

I find a list of `Upvote` model instances attached to a specific `question`, so I can check if the current user has already upvoted the question.  I want to display a different button if the user has already upvoted this particular question.  The problem is, the current `{% if .. %}` tags don't work, because a question can have many upvotes.  I only need the `{% if ..%}` tags to simply check to see if one of the `upvote.user == request.user`.

How do I approach this situation?  I'm looking at different solutions, like creating a variable and setting that to True if a match was found (seems difficult), or writing a custom template tag.  I feel like I'm over-complicating this issue though.

---

**HTML Template**

```
{% for question in questions %}
        {% for upvote in question.upvote_set.all %}
        {% if upvote.user == request.user %}
        # Display the upvote button
        {% else %}
        # Display a different button
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    # ... code
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='question', null=True, blank=True)

class Upvote(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django template boolean expressions support an `in` operator, but I don't think you can flatten the FK relationships enough to query it with just template syntax.

You could either:

a) Add a method to the `Question` model to return a list of upvoting users:

```
def upvoters(self):
    return self.upvote_set.all().values_list('user', flat=True)
```

Then test this in the template:

```
{% if request.user in question.upvoters %}
```

Or b) Annotate the question instances in the view:

```
# assuming questions is a queryset, I think the for loop means this is redundant but I'm including it for clarity
questions = list(questions)
# then modify the model instances
for question in questions:
    question.is_upvoted = question.upvote_set.filter(user=request.user).exists()
```

Then check `{% if question.is_upvoted %}` in your template.

Keep an eye on performance with either of these, these should be fine for reasonably small numbers of questions and upvoters but aren't particularly optimized. Annotation with a [conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions) is probably more efficient but outside of my direct experience.

Comment: I love you.  I just managed to solve it with your first solution.  We would need to add pk to `request.user` because `values_list('user')` returns the pk of the user.  Thus by using `{% if request.user.pk in question.upvoters %}`, it works!  I'm not too concerned with heavy duty traffic handling so this will do for now.